# Почему я не могу уточнить неполный ответ у другого участника?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, привилегии

Вот я увидел комментарий и хочу его уточнить. Но выяснилось, что почему-то я это сделать не могу: мой коммент должен-де содержать ответ. Так зачем мне писать то, что уже кем-то сказано для того, чтобы вставить пару слов от себя? Тогда проще просто копировать чужие слова и повторно их публиковать от своего имени с добавлением пары слов от себя. Но ведь это неприлично. С другой стороны, можно пересказать данный ранее коммент своими словами. Но зачем на это тратить время?

Comment: Будте пожалуйста конкретны, привидите ссылку.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, похоже что вы не различаете "комментарий" под ответом/вопросом и "ответ" в теме. Толи вы пишете о том, что комментарий слишком короткий (менее 15 символов), толи у вас менее 50 баллов репутации, поэтому возможности комментирования ограничены. (В этом случае рекомендуется набрать 50 баллов и комментировать под ответом.)

Comment: [Пример вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929373/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-latex/959050#959050) . Неужели вы это не видели? А баллов у меня действительно меньше 50: 40. Поэтому мне недоступен коммент и я запихал его в ответ, но от этого он (коммент) не стал выглядеть ответом. Все, я понял. Ну, набрать еще 10 баллов быстро, наверное, не удастся: я, скорее, математик, чем программист.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы писать комментарии, [надо набрать всего 50 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - тебе ещё 16 осталось.

Comment: вот зачем только нужно это глупое ограничение на 50 баллов для комментирования

Comment: @mymedia, чтобы человек сначала разобрался, что стоит писать в комментариях?

Comment: @Qwertiy в итоге у нас тотально замусориваются ответы

Comment: @andreymal, ну предложи поменять отдельным вопросом и обоснуй? Если не ошибаюсь, сайты могут сами регулировать лимиты привилегий в настройках.